# How to ask if I can use a rewards/points card at a paid lunch?

Tags: united-states, politeness, meetings

I am meeting with a recruiter, and she is taking me to lunch (paid for by her company) at restaurant that is local to my company's location. She is unlikely to have a loyalty card at this place because her company is far enough away that it would not be a regular visit for her like it is for me and my coworkers.

The day of the week we are meeting is the restaurant's weekly day that a loyalty card earns 10% off the total bill. Is there a tactful, not-greedy way to ask if I can use my card to save her money and earn me some points? The loyalty card is applied to the bill, so if she's paying it will still work to save her 10% of the price.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm almost certain the recruiter won't mind that you at least ask to use your loyalty card, and will probably be happy and grateful that you will be saving 10% off the bill. I would bring it up before you actually go to the place, as to avoid confusion and to give her a chance to make sure that it is allowed.

**Don't mention that you will gain points.**  While it may be likely that the recruiter will not care, there is a chance that she might think you are being greedy.  And besides, the 10% is a good enough reward as it is.

Answer (score 1):

How can you ask? - Simply mention that you have a loyalty card for the place, it will save 10% off the bill.

Now what is her answer to be, surely it must be "yes"; or she will explain why it is "no".

If she *needs* to spend a particular amount in order to avoid a clawback such a *savings* would be unwelcome.

What if her boss takes her there for a annual meet-the-boss lunch or they happen to be in the area, would the boss expect that she would offer her card, and her not connecting this (and not having a card) fails to do so, secretly souring the lunch and meet-and-greet ...

If you are old friends with the recruiter I see no problem brining this up.

If you're not quite that close you don't want to make "yes" a forced answer or "no" a difficult explanation - is it for her benefit (no, she's not paying), it's for your benefit; if her boss is a penny pincher they'll likely appreciate it.

It's somewhat comparable to going on a first date and pulling out coupons.

Nickel and diming is usually best kept out of business discussions as a general rule. Example: You're in an interview and after running the gauntlet they ask what you expect to be paid, you make a fair offer to which they ask if you'd accept a dollar an hour less; sure, for half the workload ...

What can you gain versus what can you lose. If you gain 10 points is it worth 10¢?, if there's anything *wrong* with the idea it's likely to cost more than 10¢, if you're good friends I foresee no problems.

Asking is easy, when paying the bill comes up simply say you have a loyalty card that would entitle her to 10% off - how this works out is another matter.